# Disable Screen overlay for my app or I don't want to show other apps popups in my app like Facebook Messenger popup

Tags: screen, kiosk-mode, overlays, android-screen-pinning

I want to disable popups over my custom android application. How can I do it pragmatically? I am making an application like Kiosk mode so I don't want other apps popups over my application. I am using Screen pinning mode but its shows other apps popups.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Any app which uses permission "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" can draw an overlay on top of other apps. So even if screen pinning mode is on, overlay or popup can appear but another app cannot be opened.

Comment: yes you are right but popups of Facebook Messenger still came over the app, its like a small widget with user image and you can even open it and chat with anyone and same is for Whatsapp if you enable the Show popup option from Whatsapp settings. How we can hide/disable them when our app is running ?

Comment: I tried for disabling that overlay's too but not able to achieve it yet. Maybe, If you got the answer, please post it.